# HashMap - operations

Tags: java, math, collections, hashmap, tuples

I have this situation where I have 5 people: P1, P2, P3, P4, P5.

Every person has 3 criterias to compare: A, B, C (formed from float numbers like `5.x`, so A can be `5.3` or `1.2` etc, B can be `1.8` etc, C `8.9` etc, minimum is `0.0`, maximum is `10.0`).

Every criteria has subcriterias (for example 6 subcriterias also formed from float numbers like `2.x`): A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 / B1, B2, B3,... You get the idea.

How can I put this 5 people in a HashMap (or any other collection) with their respective criterias and sub criterias:

```
HashMap<String, List<Float>> person = new HashMap<String, List<Float>>();
```

and do the following operations:

1. Take the first criterion from every person (A) and take out the min/max from it, that means from P1-A, P2-A, P3-A, P4-A, P5-A will remain maybe P1-A, P2-A, P3-A, with their respective subcriterion numbers, P1-A-A1, P1-A-A2, P1-A-A3... / P2-A-A1, P2-A-A2, P2-A-A3, and so on.
2. Because the min/max is out, the criterions remaining P1-A, P2-A, P3-A means that only P1, P2, P3 are still in the game, P4 and P5 are out. The next operation is to calculate the average between P1 criterion A subcriterion A1, P2 Criterion A subcriterion A1 and P3 criterion A subcriterion A1. This should be calculated for every subcriterion like this:

   ```
   result1 = (P1-A-A1 + P2-A-A1 + P3-A-A1)/3

   result2 = (P1-A-A2 + P2-A-A2 + P3-A-A2)/3
   ```

   6 in total for criterion A.
3. For criterion B and C, is the same operation from point 1. and 2.
4. I need to inject the numbers for criterions A, B, C and subcriterions A1...A6, B1...B6, C1...C6 for every person P1...P5, there is no link between the value of A and values of A1, A2...A6, B1...etc, just the operations count in the end.

I think the best will be to create the persons hasmaps with criterion as the key and subcriterions as values.

Comment: no, it is for personal use

Comment: This shows distinct object phobia. It seems that you should create a sensible class structure.

Comment: And it sounds way too abstract to be “for personal use”.

Comment: @Holger but aren't you always needing to _inject numbers of criterions (sic) A, B and C_ in your personal life? I know I am...

Comment: yeah, still no one knows

Comment: This something you're still looking into?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you need to access a specific person by a key, so you don't need a `HashMap`, just a `List`.

But the criteria are referenced by keys, so you should do something like this:

```
enum CriteriaKey {
   A, B, C
}

enum SubcriteriaKey {
   ...
}

class Criteria implements Comparable<Criteria> {
  private Float value;
  private Map<SubriteriaKey, Subcriteria> ...
}

class Subcriteria implements Comparable<Subcriteria> {
  private Float value;
  ...
}

class Person {
  private Map<CriteriaKey, Criteria> ...
}
```

Then you implement the methods performing your operations in those classes.

Comment: well, i thought putting in a HashMap will be easier.

Comment: i don't know how to do it in your way.